# get the name of model and title of another model in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i want to get the name of model genre and title of model list in the partial view but @genre.Lists.Title doesn't work
this is my genre model

```
  public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my List model

```
 [Bind(Exclude = "ListId")]
public class List
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Maker")]
    public int MakerId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An List Title is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 100.00,ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("List URL")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string ListUrl { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Maker Maker { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and this my actionResult

```
  public ActionResult Navbar()
    {

        var genres = storeDB.Genres.Include("Lists").ToList();



        return PartialView("Navbar",genres);
    }
```

and this is my PartialView

```
    @model IEnumerable<Store.Models.Genre>
    @foreach (var genre in Model)
    {
        @genre.Name
        @genre.Lists.Title
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`@genre.Lists` is of type `List<List>`, not `List` (by the way, I would rename your class somehow, it's easy to confuse with the standard library class of this name).

So you either need another `foreach` loop to iterate over `@genre.Lists` or you can get the first element with `@genre.Lists[0].Title`. It's up to you what you actually want to achieve. For example, you could use `string.Join`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Store.Models.Genre>
@foreach (var genre in Model)
{
    <text>
        @genre.Name
        @string.Join(", ", genre.Lists.Select(x => x.Title))
    </text>
}
```

Or write some real HTML. Again, depends what you want your output to be.

Comment: The `<text>` tags are not necessary at all, but it wont look good - putting the values in a table would be more appropriate